# "no such file or directory" - but lists a file location that has not been specified

Tags: r, rstudio, rna-seq, sequencing, nomachine

I am running QC for bulk RNAseq and ran the following code:

```
base_dir <- "/data/dpag-paupar-kap1/mert4522/FASTQ/0.2Data2"
fastqc_dir <- "/data/dpag-paupar-kap1/mert4522/FASTQ/0.2Data2"

fastqc(fq.dir = base_dir, qc.dir = fastqc_dir, threads=4)
```

which for some reason is giving the following error:

```
sh: /home/mert4522/bin/FastQC/fastqc: No such file or directory
Warning: error in running command
```

I am running this via RStudio in a NoMachine window (remotely connecting to my University high performance computing server).
I am mystified by this error message because I know that this file does not exist, which is why I specified a different filepath. The wd is set to /data/dpag-paupar-kap1/mert4522.

Any advice?

tried changing file locations and filepaths, installing and uninstalling fastqcr package

Comment: It looks like that is the location where the package is searching for the `fastqc` executable. The paths you are providing are the paths where the files are. I don't know what package you are using though, so I can't give specific advice.

Comment: If you are using `fastqcr`, you should probably use the `fastqc.path` argument to point the package to where on the server `FastQC` is installed.

Comment: @Axeman I thought of this - but when I try it I still get the same error message! Even when I move the location where FastQC is installed :(

Comment: So if you run `fastqc(fq.dir = base_dir, qc.dir = fastqc_dir, fastqc.path = 'your_path_here')`, you still get `sh: /home/mert4522/bin/FastQC/fastqc: No such file or directory`? Or `sh: your_path_here: No such file or directory`?